# openCV libraries for C code in Ubuntu and laptop camera usage

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, camera

I am trying to use openCV to get images from the camera install in my laptop (running Ubuntu 11.04), and I have some questions/problems:

1. I have checked that some code examples use the following includes:

   #include "cv.h"

   #include "highgui.h"

   but once I compile the code, errors are given due to those includes. How can I set those packages/libraries to be used in my code? I try doing it following this website http://www.samontab.com/web/2011/06/installing-opencv-2-2-in-ubuntu-11-04/ but no success.
2. Once an image is loaded in an object IplImage*, how can I sent it through a socket? I have though about saving it to a file using "cvSaveImage(fileName,img)", and then open such file and send it (which I have no problem with, since I have sent files .bmp and .jpg through sockets), but I not sure whether this may be the optimal way to do it. I have checked that the structure IplImage have several fields, but I am not sure which one of them can be used for my purpose.
3. How can I get the variable of the camera of my laptop as parameter for cvCaptureFromCAM in openCV?

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide.

Comment: Did you check that the OpenCV headers and libraries are actually present in `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I checked the folders that you mentioned, and the openCV headers and libraries are not there. How should I fix that issue?, ie, how to correctly install openCV in Ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: You need to go through the OpenCV installation process again carefully and make sure you didn't omit any steps and that there were no errors. You should then have the required headers and libraries in `/usr/local/opencv`, `/usr/local/opencv2`, etc.

Comment: Are the steps described in openCV website (http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) enough to install it correctly? or are they described for people with advanced experience in Linux? I am not an expert in Ubuntu. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, if you follow the instructions carefully you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a problem with the Ubuntu distro, but once that was issue was solved, then there was no problem with writing codes using openCV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I was facing was that I was installing openCV for a different version of Ubuntu. Once I install the right method for the appropiate version of Ubuntu the mentioned problems in my question disappeared, using "0" as index for my laptop camera.